# Image capture when ARCORE sharing camera with Camera2 API

Tags: java, android, android-camera, arcore, android-camera2

I'm trying to capture an image using the ARCORE. Followed the code base of the shared camera sample provided on this rep (https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk) and implemented a code to build the camera capture request.

I am using an image reader for the preview and another with high resolution for the capture and this is allowed (https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/camera-sharing).

When building the request I got the exception of "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CaptureRequest contains unconfigured Input/Output Surface!" and I already added the image reader surface to the list of surfaces as mentioned on the site of shared camera config.

Here's the code for the capture request builder:

```
public void shotPhoto() {
    try {

      // Get the characteristics for the ARCore camera.
      CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(this.cameraId);

      // Get the higher resolution for image capture
      StreamConfigurationMap streamConfigurationMap = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
      Size[] sizes = streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class);
      int width = sizes[0].getWidth();
      int height = sizes[0].getHeight();

      reader = ImageReader.newInstance(
                      width,
                      height,
                      ImageFormat.JPEG,
                      2);
      reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(this, backgroundHandler);

      sharedCamera.setAppSurfaces(this.cameraId, Arrays.asList(reader.getSurface()));

      CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(cameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
      captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
      captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, SensorOrientation);
      CaptureRequest captureRequest = captureRequestBuilder.build();
      captureSession.capture(captureRequest, cameraCaptureCallback, backgroundHandler);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a fairly old question but having run into this recently I thought I would add an answer.

The ImageReader's surface needs to be in the list of surfaces that is passed into cameraDevice.createCaptureSession. But you only want to take snapshots - you don't want it to be populated on every frame - so don't add it to the list of surfaces for captureSession.setRepeatingRequest, and also don't make the call to sharedCamera.setAppSurfaces.

Of course that means you need to create your ImageReader earlier in the program's execution so that its surface is available at the time you create the capture session.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).